# Problems with $timeout function

Tags: angularjs, timeout

Im new in AngularJS. Please can you help with resolving problem with $timeout in Angular JS 1.8.
I have some course on Udemy, but i think its little outdated :(. Many thanks for your help. PS: Sorry for my english.

```
//index
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
</div>
</body>

//app.js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myAppCtrl", function ($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.name = "John";
$timeout([function () {
    console.log("Peter");
}], 3000);
});
```

Many thaks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$timeout([function () {
    console.log("Peter");
}], 3000);
```

To this

```
$timeout(function() {
    console.log("Peter");
), 3000);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help Raxel. It works fine now. Have a nice day